# Format google places JSON output

Tags: list-manipulation, version-9, json-format

I'm have some trouble formatting the Output of a 'Import' request.
I get this as a return of a google places API request:

```
out={"html_attributions" -> {}, 
    "results" -> {{"geometry" -> {"location" -> {"lat" -> 48.35593, 
    "lng" -> 10.89459}}, 
    "id" -> "4f8d22dd53bf7c6eb79360a324ce616999b82b5f", 
    "place_id" -> "ChIJA7PvOkG9nkcRmJkimVDMQQ4", 
    "reference" -> 
    "CmRcAAAAdwzUsk-\
     DX8sUI1HMyFVujZ2gu8claGrxhJ8ZVj80rBBEkbiiLtQnqCalgnOvIMkHF17f5TzkB6hXc\
     STLG36HPB_KU08JczxpHSIpc1Z4UlKqhTHXTShYTKimqxowUsUBEhBRY_fMjrk_\
     UIiaZ9U1MMPsGhQPwm98QfAw74FogeUryqxPxGMv8g"}, {"geometry" -> \
     {"location" -> {"lat" -> 48.3747, "lng" -> 10.8957}}, 
     "id" -> "6d4568d42a2011543410ab2d0d805b521562a237", 
     "place_id" -> "ChIJBzM8CmgenEcRqrj1bDQ6WDY", 
     "reference" -> 
     "CmRZAAAAqcP7N7Cv35I_HLTMKiuYajWRh6qFNadB_\
      trryO8EgtOYhyz2Wjfq7sYaKAwXKU_5HLq4tB1tS5_f4QZNDeM_\
      lUEd8XI74DNz5CntTTbGIdOPs0hYsb6MOvitVUBT1PaoEhCo3qnHXZYwLyX8vhRapm9LGh\
      QzEWMmVxnp1wpetlGDMlp_OC55QQ"}}, "status" -> "OK"}
```

by trial and error I found a way to get the location of the first place:

```
out[[2, 2]][[1, 1]][[2, 1]]

"location" -> {"lat" -> 48.35593, "lng" -> 10.895}
```

the second place is

```
out[[2, 2]][[2, 1]][[2, 1]]

"location" -> {"lat" -> 48.3747, "lng" -> 10.8957}
```

the number of places is

```
Length[out[[2, 2]]]

2
```

For longer outputs I'd like to get all locations automatically. My naive approach was

```
[[2, 2]][[#, 1]][[2, 1]]&/@out
```

but that does not work.

How can I get a structured output of all the location data from this JSON output?

I'm also looking for general advice how to best handle google places and JSON output.

Perhaps someone even knows a nice way to autmatically display the geodata on a map in mathematica.

Please provide a mathematica9 answer as I only have this version. But I might buy v10 soon so I'm also interested in the new v10 features :)

Comment: `[[2, 2]][[#, 1]][[2, 1]]&/@out` is simply not correct syntax.  Did part of that line get removed when you pasted it?

Answer (score 7):

With Mathematica 10 or later, I recommend converting this data structure to either an Association or a Dataset:

```
asc = Replace[out, r : {__Rule} :> Association[r], {0, Infinity}];

ds = Dataset[asc]
```

Then you can index it with the keys, e.g.

```
asc[["results", 1, "geometry"]]
(* <|"location" -> <|"lat" -> 48.35593, "lng" -> 10.89459|>|> *)

asc[["results", 1, "geometry", "location", "lat"]]
(* 48.35593 *)
```

Note: the difference between `asc[[ ... ]]` and `asc[ ... ]` is that the latter doesn't allow for numerically indexed parts, only for keys.

---

With Mathematica 9 or earlier, we can use `/.` to extract parts of rule lists.  For example, to get `"a"` from `rules = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}`, we can use

```
"a" /. rules
```

Starting from this idea and the observation that JSON dictionaries use strings as keys, we can write a simple part extractor:

```
jsonPart[data_, part_String] := part /. data (* for rule lists *)
jsonPart[data_, part_Integer] := data[[part]] (* for arrays *)

jsonPart[data_, partList_List] := Fold[jsonPart, data, partList] (* multiple part specifications *)
```

Then:

```
jsonPart[out, {"results", 1, "geometry"}]
(* {"location" -> {"lat" -> 48.35593, "lng" -> 10.89459}} *)

jsonPart[out, {"results", 1, "geometry", "location", "lat"}]
(* 48.35593 *)
```

This is meant only as a simple example, without error checking.  If you are going to use this several times, it's probably a good idea to implement some error checking as well (make sure that the dictionary key is actually in the list before attempting to extract it).

Comment: Association is a mathematica10 feature, isn't it? I only have v9 :(

Comment: @spore234 Please update the question and mention this.

Comment: @spore234 I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Cases` with `HoldPattern` for these types of structures:

```
Cases[out, HoldPattern["location" -> latlon_] :> {latlon[[1, 2]], latlon[[2, 2]]}, Infinity]
```

> `{{48.3559, 10.8946}, {48.3747, 10.8957}}`